# How do can I get links to act independent of each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code currently allows any link clicked under citations to open a new page. I'm trying to exclude the "More..." links from performing this function since these are used to add more links to the current page. Is there a way to do this?

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FYyr9/)

Here's my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
  var url = 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/504216b6e4b04b508bfd333b?
format=jsonp&fields=relationships,title,body,contacts';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (json) {
      var citeCount = 0;
      var piCount = 0;
      $('#project').append('<li><b><a href="' + url + '">' + json.title + '</a> - </b>' + json.body + '</li>');
      $('#project a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (citeCount == 1) {
          return;
        }
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/itemLink    
/504216b6e4b04b508bfd333b?format=jsonp',
          jsonpCallback: 'getSBJSON',
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function (json) {
            // Loop function for each section (10 citations per section)
            var loopSection = function (start, stop) {
              // Http setup for all links
              var linkBase = "http://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/";
              // Link for citation information
              var link = "";
              for (var j = start; j < stop; j++) {
                // Create a link using the realtedItemId
                link = linkBase + json[j].relatedItemId;
                // Title links                                 
                var $anchor = $("<a>", {
                  href: link,
                  id: "id" + j,
                  text: json[j].title
                });
                // .parent() will get the <li> that was just created and append to 
                //the first citation element
                $anchor.appendTo("<li>").parent().appendTo("#citations");
              }
            }
            var itemCount = json.length;
            var numSections = Math.floor((itemCount / 10));
            var moreLinks = $('<a href="" id="nextLink">More...</a>');
            var loopCount = 1;
            loopSection(0, 10);
            $('#citations').append(moreLinks);
            $(moreLinks).on('click', function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              if (numSections > 1) {
                loopSection((loopCount * 10), ((loopCount + 1) * 10));
                $('#citations').append(moreLinks);
                numSections -= 1;
                loopCount++;
              } else if (numSections <= 1) {
                $("#nextLink").closest('a').remove();
                loopSection((loopCount * 10), json.length);
              }
            });
          },
          error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
          }
        }); // END Second .ajax call
        $('#project').on('click', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (piCount == 1) {
            return;
          }
          for (var i = 1; i < json.contacts.length; i++) {
            $('#piHeading').append('<ul>' + "Name: " + json.contacts[i].name + ', ' + "Email: " + json.contacts[i].email + ', ' + "Phone: " + json.contacts[i].phone + '</ul>');
          }
          piCount++;
        });
        citeCount++;
      }); // END Project link click event
      $('#citations').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open('CitationsInfo.html', '_self');
      });
    },
    error: function (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  }); // END First .ajax call              
}); // END Doc.ready
```

and Here's my html,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="MainPage4.js"></script>
<script src="Citations.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Project</h2>

<div class='wrapper'>
<ul id='project'></ul>
</div>

<h3>Citations</h3>

<div class='wrapper'>  
<ul id='citations'></ul>   
</div>

<h3>Principal Investigators</h3>

<div class='wrapper'>    
<ul id='piHeading'></ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Thanks Blazemonger that's good information to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the part of your code that is handling the global click event for the `#citations` container to include logic to filter out clicks where the target is the `#nextLink`, it should do what you want.

```
$('#citations').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(e.target).is($('#nextLink'))) {
        window.open('CitationsInfo.html', '_self');
    }
});
```

Removing the above section entirely also allow the "More..." link to work correctly, while still maintaining functionality on the individual links. The citations click event is masking the other behaviors.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6z9R/)

Comment: Wow, works GREAT thanks Ruben! Question if you get a chance to answer, so is the code you wrote basically saying if the event target clicked is #nextLink = false ?

Comment: @jc72 Essentially, yes. It is saying that the place where the click event initiated is not the `#nextLink`. The above handler is bound to one of the parents of all of the links. So, left unattended, it will trigger anytime you click on the overall container or any of its children (and their children, and so on). All event handlers have an event target which is the place where the event initiated. The event then gets bubbled up the DOM. So we are just blocking it from happening in that very specific case. However, if you leave it the way it is, you may still run into issues with the other links

Comment: that makes sense and for now I'm just going to leave it the way it is. The other links are giving me fits too, so I might have to post another question on the board since it's kind of complicated. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @jc72 Just as a quick hint that might help you out while you are looking at your code. You might find [`e.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to be helpful in some of your lower level handlers. This will make sure that if the user clicks on a link, for example, that event will not trigger the parent's click handler as well.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip Ruben, I made some changes and that method works great!!